# Can't authenticate user by its token, Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected

Tags: devise-token-auth

I am trying to get current_user but non the user is authenticated by header on API request.
Header include `access-token`, `client` and `uid` but it doesn't authenticate and shows following errors:

For reference please check this [repo](https://github.com/SahSantoshh/devise_token_auth_demo)

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 398625ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms | Allocations: 1598457)
```

Response:

```
{
 "errors": [
    "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
 ]
}
```

Header Response on sign_in:
[image]

Request for profile, demo endpoint

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/tweets' \
--header 'client: TeS-DWwybwxqh9l3ZMn__A' \
--header 'uid: sahsantoshh@gmail.com' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer e1tO5DawJq0iISdsgOk-fg'
```

Answer (score 0):

The request was missing with **access-token** and **expiry**

Actual Request is

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/tweets' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'client: TeS-DWwybwxqh9l3ZMn__A' \
--header 'uid: sahsantoshh@gmail.com' \
--header 'expiry: 1616149988' \
--header 'access-token: sjdinlkiijklnlaosihda' \
```